# Can a span be closed using <span />?

Tags: html, css, layout

```
<span class="drop" />
```

Can HTML spans be closed like this?

Comment: Don't bother, `<span class="drop"></span>` isn't that much more to type, and it's definitely supported.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Whether or not this is valid depends on your [doctype](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_DOCTYPE.asp), basically whether or not you're using XHTML or HTML.

When using XHTML, all major browsers will support self closing tags like the example you provided. Take the following example, this is valid because I'm specifying the page is using XHTML (in other words, HTML that is valid XML).

**Update:** Based on the very good comments below, browsers will only interpret all self closing tags correctly if the mime type is `text/xml` or `application/xhtml+xml`, see [here](http://webkit.org/blog/68/understanding-html-xml-and-xhtml/) for the details. For pages served as `text/html` (the vast majority), see [here](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_byfunc.asp) here for the tags that can be self closing.

This example will validate:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <h2>Will test page</h2>
    <p>some stuff <span class="drop" /></p>
</body>
</html>
```

However, this example is not valid, because I've switched the doctype to HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <h2>Will test page</h2>
    <p>some stuff <span class="drop" /></p>
</body>
</html>
```

A few helpful references:

- [W3C Validator](http://validator.w3.org/)
- [XHTML vs HTML](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_xhtml.asp)

Comment: Good way to point out that HTML (which came from SGML) is not XML.  It just kind of looks like XML and you can apply tricks to kind of pretend it's like XML.

Comment: "When specifying a doctype of XHTML, all major browsers will support self closing tags like the example you provided.". Completely wrong. Validators will accept it, but browsers won't. Browsers require the page to be served with an XML content type, before they'll support self closing tags like this.

Comment: As @Alochi said, the HTML may be valid (which is cute), but what is the use if it isn't supported by browsers? Look at this example: http://jsbin.com/ujayu3/2 . According to your answer, nothing should be red. In fact, the browser behaves as if the span isn't closed;

Comment: Thank you Alohci and Kobi, you've helped to clarify this much better than I did.

Comment: I wanted to point out that even if the doctype is XHTML and passes the w3c validator browsers will interpret the document in unexpected ways. For example, if you add this to the first example: '<p>some stuff <span class="drop" /><b>I should not be part of the span!</b></p>'. Based on the XML document the span tag is closed, so the rest of the content should be part of the parent paragraph and not the span itself. However, when you open it in Chrome and inspect the DOM it will look like this: '<span class="drop"><b>I should not be part of the span!</b></span>' which is incorrect.

Comment: If anyone knows why that happens and can shed more light on this issue, please post your findings.

Answer (score 13):

No, this isn't supported by all browsers.
Here's an example with divs: http://jsbin.com/upovu

Comment: +1 This is the real point here: even if the XHTML spec technically allows for self-closing tags, if the browsers don't support it it hardly matters. :(

Answer (score 3):

Testing the following fragment on [validator.w3.org](http://validator.w3.org/):

```
<p><span class="drop" /></p>
```

Validating as HTML 4.01 Strict

```
# end tag for "SPAN" omitted, but its declaration does not permit this
```

Validating as XHTML 1.0 Strict

```
# The uploaded document was successfully checked as XHTML 1.0 Strict.
```

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way to check is using http://validator.w3.org/

And the answer is no.

Answer (score 1):

- [In HTML: you cannot](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/intro/sgmltut.html#didx-element-3).
- [In XHTML: you can](http://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#sec-starttags).
- [In HTML Compatible XHTML: you cannot](http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml-media-types/#C_2).

You must write HTML compatible XHTML if you wish to serve it as text/html, and you must serve it as text/html if you want it to work in IE <= 8.

Answer (score 0):

Since the  tag provides no visual change by itself, it doesn't make sense to me to have an auto-closing span block with no content.  The  tag provides a way to add a hook to a part of a text or a part of a document.  When the text is hooked in a span element you can add styles to the content, or manipulate the content with for example JavaScript.

However, to answer your question, yes the html code block posted is valid.

Comment: It may be, but the browsers don't get it right. As for "make sense" - you can always think on something: it can display an icon, float around, be draggable, highlight (think semi-transparent) or serve as a marker for JavaScript. I can go on and on :)

Answer (score 0):

AS far as I know, this can only be used when you set the Doctype to Xhtml.

Answer (score 0):

[This is what the spec says for HTML 4.01](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#h-7.5.4) and for [XHTML 1.0](http://xhtml.com/en/xhtml/reference/span/).

No, it's a container unlike an image or (deprecated) horizontal rule.

Comment: Horizontal rules are not deprecated.

Answer (score -1):

No http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_span.asp

The `span` tag is useful for hooking css onto a particular segment of text or part of a document. I can't think of any useful/sensible reason that a `span` tag would self close.

Comment: For example, a placeholder in which later insert content using JavaScript. (Yes, one could take it's parent and go inserting the span itself, but that might differ from page to page or be conditional etc...)

Comment: Here's a use for it: <p id="newanchorname"><span id="anchorname"/>This is the paragraph we need to link to, with either of two anchor names.</p>

Comment: I find no information about this in the provided link. Has the source been updated? Because as it stands, the link is not relevant for the question or answer.

Answer (score -1):

No, it's not.
You can close like this ONLY if you can't insert in tag something
For example: you can`t insert tag or text inside tag **img**, so you can close tag like this