# Empty UL inside LI element

Tags: html, standards, html-lists

Can anyone explain me why `<ul>` elementa cannot be empty?

And why this HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li class="header">
        <a href="#">Work</a>
        <ul/>
    </li>
    <li class="header">
        <a href="#">New</a>
        <ul/>
    </li>
    <li class="header">
        <a href="#">Ungrouped</a>
        <ul/>
    </li>
    <li class="header">
        <a href="#">Offline</a>
        <ul/>
    </li>
</ul>
```

is rendered like this:

> - Work
>
>   - New
>
>     - Ungrouped
>
>       - Offline

Comment: Is this HTML or XHTML? This is an area where they differ.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`<ul>` is not a valid self-closing tag, so browsers may treat it as though it has not been closed properly.  You should always use a closing `</ul>` tag.

For a list of valid self-closing tags, see:

[What are all the valid self-closing elements in XHTML (as implemented by the major browsers)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/97522/what-are-all-the-valid-self-closing-tags-in-xhtml-as-implemented-by-the-major-br)

Comment: Actually, this will work: <ul></ul>. So, it can be empty, but not without the closing tag

Comment: Browsers do not seem to be bothered by empty ULs but the w3c validator will give a "Line n, Column n: end tag for "ul" which is not finished" error.

Answer (score 3):

What is the sound of one hand clapping?

A list with zero items in it doesn't make sense from a document point of view, and HTML is a document markup language.

The specification therefore [defines a list](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/lists.html#h-10.2) as requiring at least one list item in it.

```
<!ELEMENT UL - - (LI)+                 -- unordered list -->
```

As for your second question, in HTML Compatible XHTML [only elements which are defined as being EMPTY](http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml-media-types/#C_3) (i.e. those in which the end tag is forbidden in HTML) may (and must) use self-closing tag syntax.

Comment: That's because browsers are designed to cope with vast amounts of crap written by people who don't know HTML.

Answer (score 1):

Because browsers (usually) don't support self closing XML-style tags. This will work:

```
<ul>
    <li class="header">
        <a href="#">Work</a>
        <ul></ul>
    </li>
    <li class="header">
        <a href="#">New</a>
        <ul></ul>
    </li>
    <li class="header">
        <a href="#">Ungrouped</a>
        <ul></ul>
    </li>
    <li class="header">
        <a href="#">Offline</a>
        <ul></ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

For more details see: [Can a span be closed using `<span />`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2816833/can-a-span-be-closed-using-span)

Comment: In this case, "usually" means at least Firefox, Safari, Opera, Chrome and IE8... :)

Comment: @zorglub76 - I never tested it, but the question I linked suggests it will work well with a different mime type: `text/xml` instead of `text/html` - which most servers serve.