# Difference <span></span> versus <span/> for CSS?

Tags: css, web, html

Still trying to get the navigation control of a new site working the way I want.

I simplified my problem to this piece of code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<head> 
    <title>Test</title> 
    <style>
        span { display: inline-block; height: 50px; vertical-align: top; background-color: Yellow; } 
        span.block { background-color: Red; width: 15px; }
    </style> 
</head> 
<body>
    <span class="block"></span><span>A B C D</span>
    <span class="block"></span><span>E F G H</span>
</body> 
</html>
```

This code renders to:

[image]

However, the spans are generated from an XSLT in Umbraco. Even if the source states <span></span> it generates <span /> like this:

```
<span class="block" /><span>A B C D</span>
<span class="block" /><span>E F G H</span>
```

This code renders to:

[image]

Why is it doing this?

What's the difference between <span></span> and <span />?

PS: In the real thing the XSLT renders to a ul with menu items. The block span is there for layout purposes (background image); that's why it has dimensions but no content.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Self closing span tags don't exist in HTML, the browser will interpret it as invalid HTML and guess what you meant.

In this case, it is probably treating this:

```
<span class="block" /><span>A B C D</span>
<span class="block" /><span>E F G H</span>
```

as:

```
<span class="block"><span>A B C D</span>
<span class="block"><span>E F G H</span></span></span>
```

You can confirm that by right clicking on your test page, then selecting Inspect Element to use the web tools, or [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/whatisfirebug) if you have that installed. The [inspector](http://www.webkit.org/blog-files/inspector-elements-panel.png) will show you the HTML tree as the browser has interpreted it.

Comment: Not always true - it dependes on the DOCTYPE - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2816833/can-a-span-be-closed-using-span. For a bit of fun, try setting a height on the span in the original question, rather than the width, and look at the very random behaviour (in IE at least!). Well, it's not really random as block level elements shouldn't be rendered if they are empty unless they have a height, but then the fact that it's a span complicates matters. Writing HTML parsers must be fun!

Comment: @dash: that example tells the browser to treat the page as xhtml instead of html, so it could be a solution if NetWave can't fix the XSLT. I'd want to double check the browser support before depending on that, I'd prefer an html5 solution.

Comment: A simple solution is probably to change the XSLT such that it renders <span>&#160;</span> or similar. Without seeing the XSLT it's hard to know. Or change those elements to DIV's, which, when empty but have a height specified, behave in the way the OP seems to want.

Comment: Douglas is correct! The spans get nested like in his example, which explains why it renders the way it does. everything makes sense now! I will look into the XSLT... Thanks all.

Answer (score 0):

I can't understand why you would need to use a `<span>` block for layout purposes? Why not just add a class to the `<span>` (or probably more appropriately a `<div>`) and apply left-padding and a background image?

```
.my-class {
    padding-left: 15px;
    background: url(images/my-image.png) no-repeat 0 50%;
}
```

Comment: Actually, I'm already doing this but I need the same effect on the other side. Think of a tab with rounded corners that has a variable width. With your code I can only show one corner. The span is my example is used for the other corner.

Comment: Depending on the importance of rounded corners in your design (sometimes we haven't a choice), however I've been lucky enough to convince some clients to not get hung up on <IE9 browsers and use CSS3. That obviously isn't a _solution_ though. Although IE8 does support the `:after` CSS pseudo-element. Maybe you could use that pseudo-element to append to the end of your list?