# knockout.mapping to access an array inside json

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin

This is my example below.
I'am using knockout.mapping plugin in my project.

I want to fill the "from" element inside mails array to My Un Ordered list  :

In the commented code I add the data that retrived form the database by using jquery ajax.

```
<!DOCTYPE html >
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/knockout-2.0.0.debug.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/KnockoutMapping2.1.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function () {
            var viewModel = {};

            $.ajax({
                url: "Service.aspx",
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: "json",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                success: function (data) {
                    //data :
                    //       {
                    //   "id":"Inbox",
                    //   "mails":[
                    //      {
                    //         "id":"1",
                    //         "from":"Abbot ",
                    //         "to":"steve@example.com",
                    //         "date":"May 25, 2011",
                    //         "subject":"Booking confirmation #389629244",
                    //         "folder":"Inbox"
                    //      }
                    //   ]
                    //}
                    viewModel = ko.mapping.fromJS(data);

                    ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
                },
                error: function (request) {
                    alert(request.responseText);
                }
            });




        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    your id is : <span data-bind='text: id' />
    <ul data-bind="foreach : mails">
        <li data-bind="value:from"></li>
    </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Any help who to bind mails to my list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/nickolsky/EVaPL/

```
your id is : <span data-bind='text: id' ></span>
    <ul data-bind="foreach : mails">
        <li data-bind="text:from"></li>
```

1. Do not self-close span
   ( [Can a span be closed using <span />?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2816833/can-a-span-be-closed-using-span) )
2. Use text binding instead of value binding for li

Comment: Self closing tags has bit me before as well. Apparently html != xml

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/ryanwfiorini/DmWYS/

I put together a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ryanwfiorini/DmWYS/) for you to see how I prefer to do it.  I like to create a class to hold my data in thus allowing for more control over it.  You can them include functions to concatenate and such.

Hope this helps.