# Bootstrap 3: Centering and fixing glyphicon labels

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Here is my [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r9xpena2/1/) with full code example.

I am trying to achieve the following to no avail:

- I want the `glyphicon-globe` to appear centered and above the "*Community*" label (`<h1>`), and I want all three elements (the glyphicon, the `<h1>` heading and `<h3>` subheading) to be horizontally-centered in the middle of the screen
- I want the "*Community*" label to appear with the correct font (see what happens when you remove the glyphicon...)

I have a feeling that the glyphicon is causing both problems:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <h1><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-globe"/>Community</h1>
            <h3>A free online community to all new fizz-comers.</h3>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Perhaps this is malformed somehow or causing weird CSS rules to fire. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

span tags shouldn't be self-closing. [Here's a better explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2816833/can-a-span-be-closed-using-span).

[This updated example](http://jsfiddle.net/seftxu1a/) should style the heading and icon the way you want. By center aligning the text in the H1, the span inside it will also center (if set to display: block). The H1 will take the full width of the container element - setting it to display:inline-block is to make this example look better.

```
<h1 style="text-align: center; display: inline-block;"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-globe" style="display: block"></span>Community</h1>
```

Comment: Thanks @Urban Dude (+1) - however in your example, the `<h1>` heading and the `<h3>` subheading are still left-aligned; I'm trying to get all three (glyphicon, heading & subheading) horizontally-centered in the middle of the screen. Any ideas? Thanks again!