# ASP.NET Core validation tag helper strange behaviour

Tags: jquery, asp.net, validation, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

Today I noticed strange behaviour of ASP.NET Core taghelper when testing validation messages.

I have no jquery-validate and jquery-validate-unobtrusive in place.

This works fine:

```
<span asp-validation-for="Name" class="text-danger"></span>
```

This is not working:

```
<span asp-validation-for="Name" class="text-danger" />
```

Any idea why?!
Is this a bug?

Thanks for your inputs!

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2816833/can-a-span-be-closed-using-span

Comment: thanks! didn't know that's also invalid in html 5...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Jonathan is correct - this an invalid element to be self-closing. Making a tag self-closing indicates that it is a [void element](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#void-elements) - meaning the tag has no content inside of it. Span tags totally have content!

However, the reason it doesn't work in Core is [because what happens on this line](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers/ValidationMessageTagHelper.cs#L91). With a self-closing tag, the `TagMode` property on the `output` variable is set to `SelfClosing`, and the `TagBuilder` isn't going to put any of the message content in to it (because it is a void element which has no content).

With a `</span>` at the end, the mode changes to `StartTagAndEndTag` and content is properly added.