# sibling span width confusion getting percentage of the preceding sibling

Tags: css

I am trying a very simple project item-list/progress display (non-interactive, just a static display) which intends to show various categories overlaid as progress boxes, like so:

```css
.plan {
   list-style: none;
}

.plan li {
    display: block;
}


.progress a {
    text-decoration: none;
}

.plan .subject {

}


.plan .progress {
    background-color: #eee;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25) inset;
    border-radius: 8px;
    margin-bottom: 1ex;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}


.progress span {
    height: 100%;
    border-radius: 8px 0 0 8px;
    display: inline-block;
}

.progress a {
    padding: 2px 1ex;
    display: inline-block;
}

.progress .done {
  background-color: lightgreen;
}

.progress .critical  {
  background-color: crimson;
}


.progress .todo  {
  background-color: cyan;
}
```

```html
<ul class="plan">
    <li>
        <div class="progress">
            <span class="done" style="width: 55%"/>
            <span class="todo" style="width: 35%"/>
            <span class="critical" style="width: 25%"/>
            <a href=".">1234567</a>
        </div>
        <span class="subject"> lorem ipsum dolor sit amet </span>
    </li>

    <li>
        <div class="progress">
            <span class="done" style="width: 80%"/>
            <span class="todo" style="width: 50%"/>
            <a href=".">8901234</a>
        </div>
        <span class="subject"> phasellus elit orci, suscipit et eros eu, consequat viverra sem. </span>
    </li>
</ul>
```

In the above example, my intention is to set width of the nested `span` elements of `div.progress`, to be the percentage of the `div.progress` box size itself.  However, as can be seen in the output, successive `span`s set their width to the percentage of their preceding sibling. 
E.g. in the first item the `55%` is that of the id box, as intended. The following `35%` is that of the `55%` which is `.55*.35 = 19.25%` of the id box), and the third `25%` width is `.1925*.25=~5%` of the id box.

How can I get the sibling span to be the percentage of the parent div?

Alternative layout suggestions would be very much appreciated. The objective here is to display individual sub-categories (e.g. `critical`, `todo`, `done`) as a percentage of a total, whose size is based on the item they overlay (here the `<a>` element with the item id). For example, they could've been sized as individual boxes which would line up as, `25%`, `10%`, and `20%` and remainder `45%` (gray) as default, respectively for the first item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope I've understood your question correctly...

I would change the HTML. Un-nest the span tags, close them correctly and wrap them in a div which will allow you to position them easier:

```
<li>
    <div class="progress">
      <div class="prog-bars">
        <span class="done"></span>
        <span class="todo"></span>
        <span class="critical"></span>
      </div>
      <a href="#">1234567</a>
    </div>
    <span class="subject"> lorem ipsum dolor sit amet </span>
  </li>
```

Then you need to make a few changes to the CSS.

Firstly, give `.progress` a position:

```
.plan .progress {
  position: relative;
}
```

Now you can style the new class, `.prog-bars`

```
.prog-bars {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 0; /*this removes white space between spans */
}
```

This places the div directly over the progress div. Now you can style the spans. (Note that you can target the border-radius more precisely also):

```
.prog-bars .done {
  background-color: lightgreen;
  width: 55%;
  border-radius: 8px 0 0 8px;
}

.progress .todo {
  background-color: cyan;
  width: 35%;
}

.progress .critical {
  background-color: crimson;
  width: 5%;
  border-radius: 8px 8px 0 0;
}
```

Now your link text will have disappeared. You need to give it a z-index so it will display over the spans. You also need to give it a position for z-index to work correctly (I'm not sure why..)

```
 .progress a {
      z-index: 444;
      position: relative;
  }
```

**[View Codepen](http://codepen.io/sol_b/pen/XNLXKy)**

**EDIT:** Assign `width:auto` to `.progress`, which will accommodate link text of varying sizes.

```css
.plan {
  list-style: none;
}

.plan li {
  display: block;
}

.progress a {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  z-index: 444;
  position: relative;
  padding: 2px;
  display: inline-block;
  color: #000;
}

.plan .progress {
  background-color: #eee;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25) inset;
  border-radius: 8px;
  margin-bottom: 1ex;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.prog-bars {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 0;
}

.progress span {
  height: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
}

.prog-bars .done {
  background-color: lightgreen;
  width: 45%;
  border-radius: 8px 0 0 8px;
}

.progress .todo {
  background-color: cyan;
  width: 25%;
}

.progress .critical {
  background-color: crimson;
  width: 10%;
  border-radius: 8px 8px 0 0;
}
```

```html
<ul class="plan">
  <li>
    <div class="progress">
      <div class="prog-bars">
        <span class="done"></span>
        <span class="todo"></span>
        <span class="critical"></span>
      </div>

      <a href="#">1234567</a>

    </div>
    <span class="subject"> lorem ipsum dolor sit amet </span>
  </li>

  <li>
    <div class="progress">
      <div class="prog-bars">

        <span class="done"></span>
        <span class="todo"></span>
      </div>
      <a href="#">8901234</a>
    </div>
    <span class="subject"> phasellus elit orci, suscipit et eros eu, consequat viverra sem. </span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: thanks your example work well! I am puzzled though. The span tags aren't nested in my version either, and closed (empty tag).  So, what exactly is the problem?

Comment: also, having a fixed "100px" size for the progress box isn't ideal: the text inside box could be of variable length. Add couple more digits to the id in your example and see the problem...

Comment: @Nick For variable length text, use width: auto instead of pixels - I've updated the codepen with a working demo.

Comment: @Nick Span elements are not self-closing in HTML5. Here is a demo of your original code: http://codepen.io/sol_b/pen/rWEmvx  -- If you inspect the code with the developer tools you'll see that the browser is closing your span tags in an awkward way - they're being nested and wrapping the link tag.

Comment: Your description and sample solution was tremendously useful, and thanks for the pointers. To be more precise, <span/> is apparently not equivalent to <span><span/> in *non-XHTML* doctypes is the issue here. More on that here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2816833/can-a-span-be-closed-using-span.