# JavaScript function fails to get reference to DOM element on second invocation

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Below is a very simple function that will set the text content of a DOM element.

```js
const display = (el, value) => {
  el.textContent = value;
};

display(document.getElementById('element1'), 'One');
display(document.getElementById('element2'), 'Two');
```

```html
<span id="element1" />
<span id="element2" />
```

Strangely enough, when invoked the second time, the function will error out with the familiar:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'textContent' of null

At first I thought that the problem might be due to the fact that the second element might not have been loaded yet at the time of execution, but:

- The script is inlined at the end of the `body` tag, so all DOM elements should have been loaded.
- Invoking the function only on the second element correctly prints `Two`.
- Replacing the calls to `display()` with `console.log(document.getElementById('element1'))` and `console.log(document.getElementById('element2'))` successfully prints out both elements.
- Changing the order of the two calls will still only display `One`, but no error occurs.

So I'm stumped. The problem presents itself both in a stacksnippet and when loaded as a separate HTML page. It occurs in both current Firefox and Chrome.

Am I missing something very obvious here? Can anyone tell me what's going on?

Comment: Your `<span>`s are nested and unclosed.

Comment: @CertainPerformance They're not nested. Are self-closing tags not or no longer supported in HTML?

Comment: Not in ordinary HTML (such as in snippet), has to be XML. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2816833/can-a-span-be-closed-using-span

Comment: Don't just assume you can close any tag within itself.  Many can, but many can't.  If in doubt use a closing tag.

Comment: @CertainPerformance Good catch, thanks. I close-voted my own question with the duplicate you provided :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
const display = (el, value) => {
  el.textContent = value;
};

display(document.getElementById('element1'), 'One');
display(document.getElementById('element2'), 'Two');
```

```html
<span id="element1"></span>
<span id="element2"></span>
```

if you correct the `span` tags then it works correctly. so you close the `span` tag correctly.

Comment: Thanks. I guess I was still stuck in XHTML world where self-closing `<span/>` tags are valid.